Unable to align move a selected node along with cursor in reactflow
I have been trying to achieve a feature in reactflow such that when a node is selected from the toolbar, it will move along with the cursor to a position where is it going to be dropped. The problem I have here is that, when the cursor is moving, the selected/picked node does not align perfectly with it. It either lags or leads the cursor.
Here is the function I implemented to listened to mouse and event and update the node's position to match the position of the cursor.
 const onMoveCursor = useCallback(
    // if a node is selected, move it around with the cursor
    (event: React.MouseEvent) => {
      if (pickedNode && nodeType) {
        setNodes((prevNodes) => {
          return prevNodes.map((nd) => {
            if (nd.id === pickedNode?.id) {
              updateNodeInternals(nd.id);
              return { ...nd, position: { x: event.clientX - 200, y: event.clientY - 50 } };
            }
            return nd;
          });
        });
      }
    }, // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [pickedNode, nodeType]
  );


 <ReactFlow
        nodeTypes={nodeTypes}
        nodes={nodes}
        edges={edges}
        onNodesChange={onNodesChange}
        onEdgesChange={onEdgesChange}
        onConnect={onConnect}
        onReconnect={onReconnect}
        onMouseMove={onMoveCursor}
        onClick={onDrop}
        onConnectStart={onConnectStart}
        onInit={setRfInstance}
        connectionMode={"loose" as ConnectionMode}
        defaultEdgeOptions={defaultEdgeOptions}
        onNodeDrag={onNodeDrag}
      >
        {showTips && <QuickTips />}
        <Controls
          position="bottom-right"
          onInteractiveChange={(prev) => {
            dispatch({ type: "SET_READ_ONLY", payload: !prev });
          }}
        />
        <Background variant={backgroundType} gap={12} />
        <ElementPanel />
      </ReactFlow>

The function that is responsible for picking a node from the toolbar when a node tool is clicked is:
const handleClick = () => {
    if (type === "node") {
      // set the node type
      dispatch({ payload: name as nodeTypes, type: "SET_NODE_TYPE" });
      // add the node to workspace
      const nodeID = `node${nodes.length + 1}`;
      const node: Node = {
        id: nodeID,
        data: { label: { color: name === "text" || name === "link" ? "black" : "white", text: name } },
        position: { x: 1, y: 1 },
        type: name,
      };
      // @ts-ignore
      setNodes([...nodes, node]);
      // pick the new node
      dispatch({ type: "SET_PICKED_NODE", payload: node });
    } else if (type === "edge") {
      dispatch({ payload: name as edgeTypes, type: "SET_EDGE_TYPE" });
    }
  };

